# ASP.NET MVC: Razor ActionLink Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have looked around, but have not been able to find the solution to my problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My site has views for; Home, Item, and Packaging.

On the Item/detail page, I have created the following link which, in this example, is passing on ItemID for Item 73:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Packaging/Create", new { id = Model.ItemID })
```

It links to here within Item View:

```
             http://localhost:52618/Item/Packaging/Create/73
```

But, I would like it to link here in the Packaging View instead:

```
             http://localhost:52618/Packaging/Create/73
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that when you don't pass "Controller" the `Html.ActionLink` pick the current controller.

Solution is to pass the controller in `Html.ActionLink` function call. You need to use correct overload of [LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Packaging", new { id = Model.ItemID }, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Packaging", null, new { id = Model.ItemID })
```

Params:
1. Link text
2. Action name
3. Controller name
4. Route values
5. Html attributes

Comment: Do we have overload as `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)` so it will not work,  just for record not downvoted

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionLink` first parameter, is the name of the method that'll be called, and the second one is the name of the controller.

You should do something like that i think

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Packaging", new { id = Model.ItemID })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have something like an area defined. In that case you need to specify additional parameter like following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Packaging", new { area = "", id = model.ItemID}, null)
```

I have not tested the code, but it should be along these lines. Specifying an empty area will create a link that points to the controller outside of the currently active area.

Comment: `area = ""` will have no effect as area is not defined, however it will work due to correct overload